# Python strings are not immutable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

till now I belived that Python strings are immutable but when I tried this I got confused

```
>>> a
'hello world !'
>>> id(a)
140521043795728
>>> a+="d"
>>> id(a)
140521043795728
>>> a+="d"
>>> id(a)
140521043795728
>>> a
'hello world !dd'
```

if I use `+=` operator, it doesn't change the object id although string has changed.  what is happening in this case?

now this is bit different? https://ideone.com/eg1SIN

can somebody explain what is happening here?

Comment: Try adding `b = a` before appending, leaving `b` unchanged, and printing both the id's of `a` and `b`.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: https://ideone.com/eg1SIN 
what is with this?

Comment: @William_Wilson: yeah i have seen but thats bit different observation.

Comment: Python simply reused the ID, but the phenomenon of immutable strings and variables is exactly the same. I do however see the use in expanding the information found in the link I posted.

Comment: That is the memory address, you no longer use the original `a` object so python is free to reuse the address. As Colonel commented, keep a reference to `a` and you will see different behaviour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) returns an integer value that is unique to the object you pass it. If `a` is the only reference to the string `'hello world !'`, then doing `a += "b"` may end the lifetime of the string `'hello world !'` before the string `'hello world !b'` is created, so the ID of the old string is reused (which is perfectly valid behavior).

Adding another reference to the string `'hello world !'` (for example, by doing `b = a` before modifying `a`) should cause the IDs to diverge.

Comment: So what is the logic/algo of creating/assigning `id` to python objects? how python interpreter assign/generate id? any source for this?

Comment: The cpython interpreter simply returns the address of the object, but that's an implementation detail. The only guarentees are that for as long as an object is live, it has a unique ID that never changes.

Answer (score 1):

The string objects themselves are immutable, however, according to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.

Comment: According to the Python documentation, two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value. I corrected my answer to reflect this.

Comment: The *object* is a memory address

Comment: This is correct.  As the builtin help puts it: ```id(obj, /)
    Return the identity of an object.  This is guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects.
    (CPython uses the object's memory address.)``` So it's unique for as long as it exists, but memory addresses can be reallocated during a session.