# Special case when += for string concatenation is more efficient than =

Tags: python, string, concatenation, string-concatenation, python-3.11

I have this code using python 3.11:

```py
import timeit

code_1 = """
initial_string = ''
for i in range(10000):
    initial_string = initial_string + 'x' + 'y'
"""

code_2 = """
initial_string = ''
for i in range(10000):
    initial_string += 'x' + 'y'
"""

time_1 = timeit.timeit(code_1, number=100)
time_2 = timeit.timeit(code_2, number=100)

print(time_1)
# 0.5770808999950532
print(time_2)
# 0.08363639999879524
```

Why `+=` is more efficient **in this case**?
As far as I know, there is the same number of concatenation, and the order of execution doesn't change the result.

Since strings are immutable, it's not because of inplace shinanigans, and the only thing I found about string concat is about `.join` efficiency, but I don't want the most efficient, just understand why `+=` seems more efficient than `=`.

With this code, performances between forms almost equals:

```py
import timeit

code_1 = """
initial_string = ''
for i in range(10000):
    initial_string = initial_string + 'x'
"""

code_2 = """
initial_string = ''
for i in range(10000):
    initial_string += 'x'
"""

time_1 = timeit.timeit(code_1, number=100)
time_2 = timeit.timeit(code_2, number=100)

print(time_1)
# 0.07953230000566691
print(time_2)
# 0.08027460001176223
```

---

I noticed a difference using different Python version (`'x' + 'y'` form):

Python 3.7 to 3.9:

```py
print(time_1)
# ~0.6
print(time_2)
# ~0.3
```

Python 3.10:

```py
print(time_1)
# ~1.7
print(time_2)
# ~0.8
```

Python 3.11 for comparison:

```py
print(time_1)
# ~0.6
print(time_2)
# ~0.1
```

---

Similar but not answering the question: [How is the s=s+c string concat optimization decided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69079181/how-is-the-s-sc-string-concat-optimization-decided)

> If s is a string, then s = s + 'c' might modify the string in place, while t = s + 'c' can't. But how does the operation s + 'c' know which scenario it's in?

In a nutshell: Optimization occur when `s = s + 'c'`, not when `t = s + 'c'` because python need to keep a ref to the first string and can't concatenate in-place.

Here, we are always assigning using simple assignment or augmented assignment to the original string, so in-place concatenation should apply in both cases.

Comment: Random guess: due to the `+=`, Python can be more confident that the LHS can be thrown away immediately, and therefore mutating it is possible. Not sure if this optimization has been implemented in CPython.

Comment: In the second piece of code the compiler optimises `'x' + 'y'` to `'xy'`

Comment: Going off what @IainShelvington says, perhaps try `initial_string = initial_string + ("x" + "y")`

Comment: "Since strings are immutable, it's not because of inplace shinanigans" - but it is! CPython has a weird optimization that breaks string immutability here. Adding *3* strings with `initial_string = initial_string + 'x' + 'y'` breaks the optimization.

Comment: @user2357112 it is optimization shinanigan, but why do you consider it "inplace" ?

Comment: @DorianTurba: Because it genuinely tries to do the concatenation in place - [it `realloc`s the first string's buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62621386/confused-why-after-2nd-evaluation-of-operator-of-immutable-string-does-not-ch/62621629#62621629). I'm trying to find a dupe target that mentions what happens with the `initial_string = initial_string + 'x' + 'y'` - I'm pretty sure I've seen a good dupe target before, but I'm having trouble locating it.

Comment: Couldn't find the dupe target. Maybe it got deleted. Writing an answer instead...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the s=s+c string concat optimization decided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69079181/how-is-the-s-sc-string-concat-optimization-decided)

Comment: @S.B unfortunately, I don’t think so because we are in the case where initial_string is the only ref to the str.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a while now, CPython has had an optimization that tries to perform string concatenation in place where possible. The details vary between Python versions, sometimes a lot - for example, it doesn't work for globals [on Python 3.11](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/99862), and it used to be specific to bytestrings on Python 2, but it's specific to Unicode strings on Python 3.

On Python 3.10, the optimization starts in [`unicode_concatenate`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Python/ceval.c#L6342), and it eventually hits a `PyObject_Realloc` inside [`resize_compact`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L1079) or [`resize_inplace`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L1176), attempting to resize the left-hand operand in place.

One fairly consistent thing about the optimization across Python versions is that it only works if the left-hand side of the concatenation has no other references, or if the only reference is a variable that the result of the concatenation will be assigned to. In your slow case:

```
initial_string = initial_string + 'x' + 'y'
```

the LHS of `initial_string + 'x'` is `initial_string`, and you're *not* going to assign the result back to `initial_string` - you're going to concatenate `'y'` to the result first. Thus, the optimization can't kick in for `initial_string + 'x'`. (It kicks in for the `+ 'y'` part, though.)

For your other cases, the optimization works. For example, in

```
initial_string += 'x' + 'y'
```

instead of concatenating `initial_string` and `'x'` and then appending `'y'`, you concatenate `'x'` and `'y'` and then concatenate `initial_string` and the result. The changed order of operations means that you're assigning the result of the `initial_string` concatenation back to `initial_string`, so the optimization applies. (Also the `'x' + 'y'` gets constant-folded away, which helps a little but isn't the primary cause of the performance difference.)

Comment: If it doesn't apply to Python 3.11 globals, why such difference in my case (I'm using 3.11)

Comment: @DorianTurba: You're not using globals. `timeit` puts the timed code in a function.

Comment: oh ok make more sense now !

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dis` module, you can see what happens:

```
In [1]: import dis

In [2]: code_1 = """
   ...: initial_string = ''
   ...: for i in range(10000):
   ...:     initial_string = initial_string + 'x' + 'y'
   ...: """
Out[2]: "\ninitial_string = ''\nfor i in range(10000):\n    initial_string = initial_string + 'x' + 'y'\n"

In [3]: dis.dis(code_1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('')
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (initial_string)

  3           4 LOAD_NAME                1 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10000)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 GET_ITER
        >>   12 FOR_ITER                16 (to 30)
             14 STORE_NAME               2 (i)

  4          16 LOAD_NAME                0 (initial_string)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 ('x')
             20 BINARY_ADD
             22 LOAD_CONST               3 ('y')
             24 BINARY_ADD
             26 STORE_NAME               0 (initial_string)
             28 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           12
        >>   30 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE

In [4]: code_2 = """
   ...: initial_string = ''
   ...: for i in range(10000):
   ...:     initial_string += 'x' + 'y'
   ...: """
Out[4]: "\ninitial_string = ''\nfor i in range(10000):\n    initial_string += 'x' + 'y'\n"

In [5]: dis.dis(code_2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('')
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (initial_string)

  3           4 LOAD_NAME                1 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10000)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 GET_ITER
        >>   12 FOR_ITER                12 (to 26)
             14 STORE_NAME               2 (i)

  4          16 LOAD_NAME                0 (initial_string)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 ('xy')
             20 INPLACE_ADD
             22 STORE_NAME               0 (initial_string)
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           12
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

(Note that this is on CPython 3.9. On 3.11 the bytecode is different, although the speed on my machine is similar.)

In the case of `code_2`, the `x` and `y` constants are folded, and one `INPLACE_ADD` is used instead of two `BINARY_ADD` opcodes.

So basically, four bytecodes are replaced by two.

In your second block of code, the `dis` output is *almost* identical, except for one `BINARY_ADD`/`INPLACE_ADD`.

```
In [8]: code_1 = """
   ...: initial_string = ''
   ...: for i in range(10000):
   ...:     initial_string = initial_string + 'x'
   ...: """
   ...: 
   ...: code_2 = """
   ...: initial_string = ''
   ...: for i in range(10000):
   ...:     initial_string += 'x'
   ...: """
Out[8]: "\ninitial_string = ''\nfor i in range(10000):\n    initial_string += 'x'\n"

In [9]: dis.dis(code_1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('')
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (initial_string)

  3           4 LOAD_NAME                1 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10000)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 GET_ITER
        >>   12 FOR_ITER                12 (to 26)
             14 STORE_NAME               2 (i)

  4          16 LOAD_NAME                0 (initial_string)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 ('x')
             20 BINARY_ADD
             22 STORE_NAME               0 (initial_string)
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           12
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE

In [10]: dis.dis(code_2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('')
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (initial_string)

  3           4 LOAD_NAME                1 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10000)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 GET_ITER
        >>   12 FOR_ITER                12 (to 26)
             14 STORE_NAME               2 (i)

  4          16 LOAD_NAME                0 (initial_string)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 ('x')
             20 INPLACE_ADD
             22 STORE_NAME               0 (initial_string)
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           12
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: But then look at the second snippet, where `initial_string = initial_string + 'x'` actually finishes *faster* than `initial_string += 'x'`. That's not consistent with the `BINARY_ADD`/`INPLACE_ADD` explanation here.

Comment: `initial_string + ('x' + 'y')` give me similar performances than `initial_string += 'x' + 'y'`. With a temporary value breaking in-place optimization, performances drops similar to `initial_string = initial_string + 'x' + 'y'`.